# Pass object from Javascript to MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have tried many different solutions from other people but have had no luck with either, and I can't seem to be able to debug javascript.

These are some of the variables just so you can see the types. All variables contain data

**My view is as follows:**

```
    var startTime = new Date();
    var images = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Images));
    var sound = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.Tones));
    var gamePlayed = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.GamePlayedId));


function SaveGameData()
    {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("Play", "Game")',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: {
                GamePlayedId: gamePlayed,
                Level: level,
                ExpectedImageName: expectedImageArray,
                ExpectedToneName: expectedToneArray,
                SelectedImageName: selectedImageArray,
                SelectedToneName:selectedToneArray,
                StartTime: startTimeArray,
                EndTime: endTimeArray
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('suc');
            },
            error: function (args) {
                alert('error');
            }
        });
    }
```

**My controller is as follows:**

```
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Play(SaveGameViewModel model)
    {
        // Do something
        return Json(new { success = true , message ="successful"});
    }
```

**My viewmodel is as follows:**

```
public class SaveGameViewModel
{
    public int GamePlayedId { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; set; }
    public List<string> ExpectedImageName { get; set; }
    public List<string> ExpectedToneName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedImageName { get; set; }
    public List<string> SelectedToneName { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime> StartTime { get; set; }
    public List<DateTime?> EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

I keep getting the error message from the ajax alert. I have tried many different things and nothing seems to work. I appreciate any help that you can give. Thanks a lot!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: If you're using form, You just need to serialize form and pass it to the controller as your controller is having `model` as an argument!

Comment: You have numerous potential problems. Your method is decorated with `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` but you don't send the token. You include the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option but don't stringify the data - wither remove the option or use `data: JSON.stringify({....}),` You have not indicated what `expectedImageArray` (and the other `xxxArray` values are)

Comment: In whatever browser you're testing this in, there should be some network tools. Use them. Look at what you're sending across and that should help you. Or have a look at Fiddler to help you t/s this.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thank you so much! the [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] was the one causing all the issues. Once I removed that and removed the contentType I see that is is now reaching my controller. How can I imlpement the XSRF token with ajax/javascript?

Comment: @MikeC. Thanks for the advice I will check out Fiddler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 issues with the code your have shown.

First your method is marked with the `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` attribute but you do not pass the token so the method will never be run. Either remove the attribute, or include it using (this assumes your form includes `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`)

```
data: { 
    __RequestVerificationToken: $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),      
    .... // your other properties
},
```

Second, your posting a javascript object so you need to remove the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` option (or alternatively you need to stringify the data using `JSON.stringify()`

Side note: Its unclear from you code why you are manually constructing an object to send to the controller. If your form controls are based on `SaveGameViewModel` and are correctly generated using the strongly typed html helpers, then you can post it all back using

```
$.ajax({
    data: $('form').serialize(),
    ....
});
```